# Koa 2. How can server response be sent 'from Promise' in router?

Tags: ajax, asynchronous, promise, koa

This is meant to be executed as a script for AJAX request:

```
app.use(route.post('/ajax_request', function(ctx) {
    var p = new Promise(function(res){
        res('Some result to be received as AJAX resp');
    });
    p.then(function (val){
        ctx.body = val; //resolved after response is sent
    });
}))
```

So how to send some asynchronously received (in this case wrapped in Promise) data back to client (as an AJAX response in this case)?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Koa 2, you should be using `async` functions for your middleware. If you're not familiar with using `async/await` or any other ES6+ features with Koa 2, I would recommend learning how to use `Babel` to transpile your code in order to allow the usage of them. If you don't want to have a transpilation step, you should currently just use Koa 1.X.

In Koa 2, the code would look like this:

```
app.use(route.post('/ajax_request', async (ctx) => {
    let p = new Promise(function(res){
        res('Some result to be received as AJAX resp');
    });

    let val = await p;
    ctx.body = val;
}));
```